# Table design for "attendance check" in NoSQL DB

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, key-value

I'm trying to use AWS recognition to pass "Attendance" and insert the record (Date&time) in a DynamoDB table for every day that a kid shows up to school, the problem is that I'm not familiar with NoSQL and I'm wondering whats the best possible way to create the table with this in mind.

Some of the attributes that I'm using are:

- Enrollment No. (PartionKey)
- First Name
- Last Name

since the date/attendance is going to be a "dynamic attribute"(whether or not the kid goes to school or not), I'm not sure if I should:

1. Create a new table for every-day/week or month and only have the enrollment No. as an attribute and have a lambda trigger to put a timestamp when the kid is spotted meaning the kid attended to class (This will have a lot ...a lot of tables, ruining the purpose of dynameDB I believe)
2. In the same table insert the attendance as an attribute and as a `list` type (which could be an array for inserting the timestamp every day the kid is spotted)..this option would make the item/table in DynamoDB weight more than it should? causing it to slow down??

Any ideas on a possible way to approach this? is there another way that's more cost and memory-optimized?

*I'm not mentioning about the triggers, lambda functions, AWS recognition for this to work since it's out of the scope of this post*

Comment: Can you explain what the enrollmentID represents? Is it the relationship between a student and a class? In order to advise on a table design, you also need to explain your expected query patterns.

Comment: enrollmentID is just the primary key that i'll use and im planning to query if a single kid went to school on any given day

Comment: Yes, but what does enrollment is represent? If I need to uniquely identify a student, is an enrollmentID sufficient for that?

Comment: yes, enrollmentID wil be a unique number for each student....

Comment: i know that the personal attributes will remain static but the attendance list will increase over time,so should i embed all in one table or should i reference to a new table for each student?? (estimating for 500 students)

Comment: You should definitely not have a new table for each student. I will create an answer detailing two possible approaches you could take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to have one table for all attendance records using `enrollmentID` as the partition key and `day` (ISO 8601 date string, like “2019-09-27”) as the range key.

This makes it simple to add an attendance—just insert an enrollmentID-date pair into your table. It’s simple to query when a student attended using a variety of key condition expressions.

- All attendance for student 123: `enrollmentID = 123`
- All attendance for student 123 in a given year: `enrollmentID = 123  and begins_with(day, “2019”)`
- All attendance for student 123 in a given month: `enrollmentID = 123 and begins_with(day, “2019-09”)`

As a bonus, you can also find all the students who attended on a given day by creating a GSI with `day` as the partition key.

Any additional data (such as first name, last name, etc.) can go in a separate table if you like or in the same table with something like “info” as the sort key value instead a real date.

---

It is also possible for you to use a list of Booleans to represent a year of attendance. You can use `enrollmentID` and `year` as the partition and sort keys.

```
{
    enrollmentID: 123,
    year: 2019,
    attendance: [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1... ],
    firstName: “John”,
    lastName: “Smith”
}
```

This is a more efficient use of storage, but it limits your query options and it’s easier to accidentally ruin your data with an off-by-one error when indexing into the attendance list.